# how to convert linkedhashmap to inverted commas except one array value

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

this is my linkedhashmap

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> jsonOrderedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
jsonOrderedMap = {MessageName=HAPPY DIWALI, MessageID =M001, ListofVehicleID =["KA 01-A-1234","KA-01-A-567"]}
```

I want result to be in

```
{"MessageName":"HAPPY DIWALI","MessageID ":"M001","ListofVehicleID ":["KA 01-A-1234","KA-01-A-567"]}
```

am using

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(jsonOrderedMap, LinkedHashMap.class);
```

to convert but am getting result as

```
{"MessageName":"HAPPY DIWALI","MessageID ":"M001","ListofVehicleID ":"[\"KA 01-A-1234\",\"KA-01-A-567\"]"}
```

with array inverted commas and slashes inside the array

Comment: What's wrong with the result? `"` needs to be escaped in java and gson did that for you automatically using `\"`.

Comment: @Hearen I think he doesn't want it to be a JSON array and not a JSON string.

Comment: OP, you better clarify your question

Comment: my linkedhashmap is {MessageName=HAPPY DIWALI, MessageID =M001, ListofVehicleID =["KA 01-A-1234","KA-01-A-567"]}  i want in this format {"MessageName":"HAPPY DIWALI","MessageID ":"M001","ListofVehicleID ":["KA 01-A-1234","KA-01-A-567"]} how i can do it please help me out